# How to understand fontconfig output: "Pattern has 38 elts (size 48)"

Tags: terminology, fontconfig

When running with verbose output, and sometime even without, the first thing fontconfig writes about any font is a line like the following:

```
Pattern has 38 elts (size 48)
```

What do these numbers represent? And are they used for?

After looking in the source code I believe "elts" is short for elements, but I still don't know what the numbers mean and if they are relevant for understanding the behavior of fontconfig.

Below is a full example of output (with some of the charset lines removed):

```shellsession
$ fc-match "DejaVu Sans" -v
Pattern has 38 elts (size 48)
        family: "DejaVu Sans"(s)
        familylang: "en"(s)
        style: "Book"(s)
        stylelang: "en"(s)
        fullname: "DejaVu Sans"(s)
        fullnamelang: "en"(s)
        slant: 0(i)(s)
        weight: 80(f)(s)
        width: 100(f)(s)
        size: 12(f)(s)
        pixelsize: 12.5(f)(s)
        foundry: "PfEd"(w)
        antialias: True(w)
        hintstyle: 1(i)(w)
        hinting: True(s)
        verticallayout: False(s)
        autohint: False(s)
        globaladvance: True(s)
        file: "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf"(w)
        index: 0(i)(w)
        outline: True(w)
        scalable: True(w)
        dpi: 75(f)(s)
        scale: 1(f)(s)
        charset:
        0000: 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 7fffffff 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
        0001: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
(w)
        lang: aa|ab|af|ar|ast|av|ay|az-az|az-ir|ba|bm|be|bg|bi|bin|br|bs|bua|ca|ce|ch|chm|co|cs|cu|cv|cy|da|de|el|en|eo|es|et|eu|fa|fi|fj|fo|fr|ff|fur|fy|ga|gd|gl|gn|gv|ha|haw|he|ho|hr|hu|hy|ia|ig|id|ie|ik|io|is|it|iu|ka|kaa|ki|kk|kl|ku-am|ku-ir|kum|kv|kw|ky|la|lb|lez|ln|lo|lt|lv|mg|mh|mi|mk|mo|mt|nb|nds|nl|nn|no|nr|nso|ny|oc|om|os|pl|pt|rm|ro|ru|sah|sco|se|sel|sh|shs|sk|sl|sm|sma|smj|smn|sms|so|sq|sr|ss|st|sv|sw|tg|tk|tl|tn|to|tr|ts|tt|tw|tyv|ug|uk|uz|ve|vi|vo|vot|wa|wen|wo|xh|yap|yi|yo|zu|ak|an|ber-dz|ber-ma|crh|csb|ee|fat|fil|hsb|ht|hz|jv|kab|kj|kr|ku-iq|ku-tr|kwm|lg|li|mn-mn|ms|na|ng|nv|ota|pap-an|pap-aw|qu|quz|rn|rw|sc|sd|sg|sn|su|ty|za(s)
        fontversion: 155320(i)(s)
        capability: "otlayout:DFLT otlayout:arab otlayout:armn otlayout:brai otlayout:cans otlayout:cher otlayout:cyrl otlayout:geor otlayout:grek otlayout:hani otlayout:hebr otlayout:kana otlayout:lao  otlayout:latn otlayout:math otlayout:nko  otlayout:ogam otlayout:runr otlayout:tfng otlayout:thai"(w)
        fontformat: "TrueType"(w)
        embeddedbitmap: True(s)
        decorative: False(s)
        lcdfilter: 1(i)(w)
        namelang: "en"(s)
        prgname: "fc-match"(s)
        postscriptname: "DejaVuSans"(w)
        color: False(w)
        symbol: False(s)
        variable: False(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not immediately obvious, a look at the [`fontconfig` documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) can help understand the statement:

> `<pattern>`
>
> Pattern elements perform list-style matching on incoming fonts; that is, they hold a list of elements and associated values. (...) Pattern elements include `patelt` elements.

> `<patelt name="property">`
>
> Patelt elements hold a single pattern element and list of values. They must have a `name` attribute which indicates the pattern element name. Patelt elements include `int`, `double`, `string`, `matrix`, `bool`, `charset` and `const` elements.

So, an "elt" is a pattern element used for font matching. They are stated as name-value pairs, and if you count the number of lines, you will find that there are indeed 38 such statements (keep in mind that the two lines after `charset:` are the "value" part of the `charset` element).

The `size` statement refers to an internal property of the underlying `FcPattern` structure. Since this output seems to be for debugging purposes (cf. its [origin](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/fontconfig/-/blob/main/src/fcdbg.c?ref_type=heads)) and the inner workings of the `FcPattern` datatype are [not documented](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-devel/x31.html), there is probably little hope to understand its actual meaning.

Comment: Thanks :) What about "size"?

Comment: @MadsSkjern See addendum (unfortunately)